# Is there any way to load js scripts in XAMPP with the same folder structure as in a regular server?

Tags: javascript, xampp

I have XAMPP and a separate cloud server. Inside XAMPP's htdocs there is a folder with a repository that I use to both develop, and push to the cloud server.

When using the same folder structure as the server ie. a script / js folder holding all the js files in the root of the folder (public_html/scripts) the server works fine.

The problem comes in development, where trying to access the scripts using src = "script/scriptname.js" gives me the error saying "Failed to load 404". Now I know it's just trying to search in localhost/scripts or htdocs/scripts rather than htdocs/projectname/scripts. I don't really want to have to move the script folder in and out all the time, as that's really tedious.

*Is there any way to use a script folder without having to move it around in Xampp?*

Comment: Use a configuration that defines the relative paths of such assets folders. And two separate definitions, either maintained manually or by autodetection.

Comment: How would one go about doing that? Is that another separate js file? Or are we using php to generate the html that calls that? Is there a separate .config file that you can use with html?

Comment: I referred to a configuration mechanism you implement for your php based logic. The HTML you hand out contains links to those asset files, right? You can generate those links in a dynamic manner, they do not have to be static. That can be done by a simple string concatenation, something like `$_config['PATH']['ASSETS'] . '/js/somefile.js`. The configuration logic itself can be primitive, maybe just a file prepended to all requests on the level of the http server, so you'd have different files getting included per service configuration offering different values to your configuration logic.

Comment: I think I understood most of that. Thanks for the help!

Last question. Is there a way for PHP to detect through a function if it's running on XAMPP or my server? Or is that really just manual

Comment: Nothing direct, since XAMPP is nothing special but just a distribution of the normal components available on all systems anyway with a single mouse click (I never understood why people use XAMPP because of that amonst other things...). But there are endless hints you can simply evaluate. However it looks like you did not understand my lines about prepending the configuration by means of the http server configuration which would mean that you only have to set that up once on each system, from then on you don't have to do anything. Google for "php_value auto_prepend_file".